# How to overwrite String depending on whether the map contains a key in java without using 'if'?

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber

I am going to use method addPresetToTaskView that will send text in selenium.
This method should use String presetValue or overwrite it if map scenarioContext contains key exactly like presetValue

I am not sure if this is the best practice.

Could you share with me your opinion please ?

```
@And("Added preset by {string} text {string} for permission {string} to data view")
public void addPresetToTaskView(String option, String presetValue, String permissionName) {
    if(scenarioContext.contextContainsKey(presetValue)) {
        presetValue = (String) scenarioContext.getContext(presetValue);
    }
                setSingleSelectformItem(presetValue, visibleTabsSelect);

}
```

Scenario context with HashMap class

```
public class ScenarioContext {

public Map<String, Object> scenarioContext = new HashMap<>();

public void setContext(String key, Object value) {
    scenarioContext.put(key, value);
}

public Object getContext(String key){
    return scenarioContext.get(key);
}

public Boolean contextContainsKey(String key){
    return scenarioContext.containsKey(key);
}
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with this. If you absolutely want to remove `if`, you can use the `Optional.ofNullable(scenarioContext.getContext(presetValue)).orElse(presetValue)` utility or a ternary statement. but that's just aesthetics.

Comment: Thanks, is there any possibility to add comment if getContext is null ?